Creating a single instance to a deformed mesh
I have a surface that I intend to use as a (non-planar) portal 
Is it possible to instance the portal surface, with deformations coming from armature and modifiers, at the place of the empty? I need an identical portal surface so both surfaces can have the Ray Portal BSDF Shader and light can move between the two.

(Using Blender 4.2.1)

Adding the following GeometryNodes modifier to a single vertex object (named "Duplicate") is a way to move this point where the empty (named "Empty") is located, then to instance on it the object (named "Cube") controlled by the armature (named "Armature").

Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

Thanks! I found that it could be a bit simpler if I just parent the duplicate to the empty and have the instance on points node directly act on input geometry
